# How to array objects reload in DataBase Table by CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, nsarray

I have one array list like this:

```
(
"08-12-2016, Thursday, Greg",
"15-12-2016, Thursday, Greg",
"22-12-2016, Thursday, Greg",
"08-12-2016, Thursday, tug"
)
```

This array list how to reload in DataBase Table with coredata

I want to like this data reload in DB Table

[image]

How can i do this. I am so tried many times but do not insert array data in DataBase Table. Please help

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried and what the issues are that you are encountering?

Comment: So you want to insert data in Coredata. what is the problem ?

Comment: What does your data model look like? If you could share a screenshot that would be great. As far as I know, you cannot store an array in CoreData unless you serialize it and store it as the NSData datatype. For this, I would have a PillDatabase and Pill entities, and give them a Many to One relationship.

Comment: My problem is solved please show bellow I founded this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

## Perfect work

```
long int counts=[resultss count];// resultss is a array list
for(int i=0;i<counts;i++)
{
    NSArray*foos = [[resultss objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSString*date_name = [foos objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString*day_name = [foos objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString*name_name = [foos objectAtIndex:2];
     NSLog(@"date_name %@",date_name);
     NSLog(@"day_name %@",day_name);
     NSLog(@"name_name %@",name_name);
    //new device
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cal" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    
    [newDevice setValue:date_name forKey:@"date"];
    [newDevice setValue:day_name  forKey:@"day"];
    [newDevice setValue:name_name forKey:@"pillname"];
    
    
    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

}
```